# Still able to select disabled dates in date picker

Tags: android, date, datepicker, android-datepicker

I want to disable the past dates of date picker in android.
i can do it by using

```
dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
```

This is working fine and the past dates in date picker looks disabled. But I can still click on a previous date and select it.
How to not let that happen ?
below is the screenshot of my date picker :-

[image]

And here is my code where I am disabling the past dates :-

```
@Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        mActivity = new WeakReference<CreateEvent>(
                (CreateEvent) getActivity());

        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);

        if(callingView==fromDate){
            dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
        }else if (callingView==toDate){
            dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(fromD);
        }

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return dialog;
    }
```

Comment: It is bug in lolipop, you can check with lower versions. For solution, you will need to apply your logic on callback of `onDateSet` method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got to know from a comment that this is a bug in Lollipop. So, fixed it programatically.

All you need to do is check the selected date with the min date set.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is a bug and you need to check the selected date using java code.

**For past Date**

```
public static boolean validatePastDate(Context mContext,int day,int month,int year){
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int currentYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int currentMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
    int currentDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    if (day > currentDay && year == currentYear && month == currentMonth) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Please select valid date", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    } else if (month > currentMonth && year == currentYear) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Please select valid month", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    } else if (year > currentYear) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Please select valid year", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

**For Future Date**

```
public static boolean validateFutureDate(Context mContext,int day,int month,int year){
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int currentYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int currentMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
    int currentDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    if (day < currentDay && year == currentYear && month == currentMonth) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Please select valid date", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    } else if (month < currentMonth && year == currentYear) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Please select valid month", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    } else if (year < currentYear) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Please select valid year", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Just pass the selected date month ,year in this method and will return boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

```
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
```

Comment: This is exactly the question. This piece of code isn't doing its job properly.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve bug for Android Lollipop you can validate date as below:

```
    int mYear,mMonth,mDay;
    Calendar mcurrentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


    DatePickerDialog mDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(context, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // validate here with condition to avoid to select past dates 
            if (selectedyear == mYear && (selectedmonth+1) == mMonth+1) {
                if(selectedday < mDay){
                    Toast.makeText(context, "invalid date", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
            }


                textview.setText(selectedday + "/" + (selectedmonth+1) + "/" + selectedyear);

        }
    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);

    mDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
    if(!mDatePicker.isShowing()){
        mDatePicker.show();
    }
```