# Disable the past date in android lollipop?

Tags: android, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

I am trying  [Date Picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32796326/still-able-to-select-disabled-dates-in-date-picker) with this link but I'm not able to fix the issue regarding  disabling past date selection in android

Comment: check this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878751/how-to-disable-dates-before-today-date-in-datepickerdialog-android

Comment: go through this link ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32796326/still-able-to-select-disabled-dates-in-date-picker

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int mYear;
        int mMonth;
        int mDay;
mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);

            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


final DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                String dateOfBirth1 = dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year;
                dobButton.setText(dateOfBirth1);

            }
        }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);

        Calendar minDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        minDate.set(mYear1, mMonth1, mDay1);
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(minDate.getTimeInMillis());
```

Comment: i have done the code for the disable date but if i select the disabled date from the calendar it should not selected so i am stuck on how to avoid selection of disable date.!!

Comment: i am not getting you properly can you plz tell me your requirement

Comment: ok ..I have already share you the link above in my question.I am able to disable the past date but if i again select the past date like 30-12-2015.its getting selected in android lollipop 5.1 i want to disable the text also or you can say disable dates should not selected.!!!!

Comment: Yes you try my code it will not displayed to you .Past date is not displayed

Comment: in your code   minDate.set(mYear1, mMonth1, mDay1); where this argument comes inside the set method did you declared it globally??