# Still able to select disabled dates in Date picker Dialog

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I want to disable the past dates of date picker in android. i can do it by using

`dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);`

This is working fine and the past dates in date picker looks disabled. But I can still click on a previous date and select it. How to not let that happen ? below is the screenshot of my date picker

[image]

Comment: add a if condition to check whether the date selected is before current date.if True,then show a toast saying "invalid date".

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32796326/still-able-to-select-disabled-dates-in-date-picker/34542301#34542301

Answer (score 0):

you can get the calendarInstance and setMinDate to current time

```
Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),   newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    mDatePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(newCalendar.getTimeInMillis());
```