# Select disabled date from date picker dialog android

Tags: android, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

I am working on date picker dialog. I want to select a date from the disabled dates which is after setting maxDate and minDate.

I gone through the following links which is suggested to disabling or avoiding selection of disabled date.

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32796326/still-able-to-select-disabled-dates-in-date-picker) and 
[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23762231/how-to-disable-past-dates-in-android-date-picker)

How could I achieve the scenario ? Need help on this.

Comment: The whole point of disabling dates is the user cannot select them. What's your use case?

Comment: @GabrielNegut Just want to indicate the disabled date not disable the selection.